# Why do I get error INVALID_OPERATION when I call glMultiDrawElementsIndirect

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm currently trying to use `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect` in with LWJGL in Java, but I have an error INVALID_OPERATION.

```
glMultiDrawElementsIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES,  GL_UNSIGNED_INT, this.modelManager.indirect, NB_TYPE_MESH, 0);
```

I see in the documentation this error is about the `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER` or `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, but I don't know where the problem is in my code.

Indirect buffer

```
int[] indirect = new int[NB_TYPE_MESH*5];
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    indirect[i] = getElementCount().get(i);
    indirect[1+i] = Game.NB_MAX_OBJECTS/2;
    indirect[2+i] = 0;
    indirect[3+i] = i==0?0:getElementCount().get(i-1);
    indirect[4+i] = i; // maybe 0
}
vboIdIndirect = glGenBuffers();
IntBuffer gIndirectBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocInt(indirect.length);
gIndirectBuffer.put(indirect).flip();
glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, vboIdIndirect);
glBufferData(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, gIndirectBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

and my elements buffer

```
vboId = glGenBuffers();
vboIdList.add(vboId);
indicesBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocInt(indices.length);
indicesBuffer.put(indices).flip();

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

indices contains indices for `NB_TYPE_MESH` types of mesh

Comment: No idea what `NB_TYPE_MESH` is supposed to be, but it is nothing related to OpenGL, and using that constant as the `drawcount` parameter of `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect` is certainly wrong.

Comment: i want to draw multiple times 2 types of mesh. so in my case NB_TYPE_MESH = 2.

Comment: @Rabbid76 i think drawcount is not the problem because if i give an other value, i got an other error, IllegalArgumentException. And if its not this function, wich function i must use ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 sorry i dont understand it's clearly do what i want.

Comment: @Joezzz See [`glMultiDrawElementsIndirect`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawElementsIndirect.xhtml). `GL_INVALID_VALUE` is generated if stride is not a multiple of four or if drawcount is negative. This doesn't seem to be the case in your code. So please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Rabbid76 oh i will edit the question but in my case its generate INVALID_OPERATION error sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a buffer is bound to the target `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER` when [`glMultiDrawElementsIndirect`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawElementsIndirect.xhtml) is called, the *indirect* argument is interpreted as an offset in basic machine units into this buffer.

Hence you need to bind the `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER` before drawing the elements, but the *indirect* argument must be `null`:

<s>`glMultiDrawElementsIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES,  GL_UNSIGNED_INT, this.modelManager.indirect, NB_TYPE_MESH, 0);`</s>

```java
glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, vboIdIndirect);
glMultiDrawElementsIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES,  GL_UNSIGNED_INT, null, NB_TYPE_MESH, 0);
```

See also [Java Code Examples glMultiDrawElementsIndirect()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.jogamp.opengl.GL4&method=glMultiDrawElementsIndirect)

Comment: After this fix i don't get error but no one object is draw.

Comment: @Joezzz What do you think I should do about it? I can't see you code and I can't debug your code.

Comment: Yes i know and its too hard to post a minimal reproducible code

Comment: @Joezzz Heads up. You solved one problem, now face the next one.